# ¿Como puedo arreglar el modo inmersivo en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

Tengo un problema con el ***Modo Inmersivo***, es que en la app esta en pantalla completa al principio pero si abro otra app y vuelvo a la mia ya el Modo Inmersivo desaparece, y tengo que cerrarla y abrirla otra vez para vuelva solo la app a ser inmersiva. Miren el codigo del Modo Inmersivo que uso:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        int UI_OPTIONS = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(UI_OPTIONS);
    }

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

Quizas sea un error en el codigo porque algunas apps si les funciona correctamente.

---

Este es el código donde tengo colocado el Inmersive Mode:

```
public class AppsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private PackageManager manager;
private List<Item> apps;

private ListView list;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_apps_list);

    loadApps();
    loadListView();
    addOnClickListener();


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        int UI_OPTIONS = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION;
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(UI_OPTIONS);
    }

    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
      }                                                                           
   }
```

Comment: Buenas tardes. En que método ejecutas este código?

Comment: Lo ejecuto dentro del @Override que tiene un metodo Protected void

Comment: Esos son todos modificadores, pero no pasaste el método. Esto te lo pregunto porque no es lo mismo que lo ejecutes en onCreate(), en onStart() o en onResume().  Podrías pasar mas código?

Comment: ok, pasare el codigo, solo donde tengo colocado el inmersive mode

Comment: Lo ejecuto en un onCreate()